# Visualize MPU6050 using openGL

Tags: opengl

After getting accelerometer/gyroscope from MPU6050, I use this function:

```
void AHRSupdate(float gx, float gy, float gz, float ax, float ay, float az,float mx, float my,float mz,double * quad) {
float norm;
float hx, hy, hz, bx, bz;
float vx, vy, vz, wx, wy, wz;
float ex, ey, ez;
double* tempQuat = quad;

// auxiliary variables to reduce number of repeated operations
float q0q0 = q0*q0;
float q0q1 = q0*q1;
float q0q2 = q0*q2;
float q0q3 = q0*q3;
float q1q1 = q1*q1;
float q1q2 = q1*q2;
float q1q3 = q1*q3;
float q2q2 = q2*q2;   
float q2q3 = q2*q3;
float q3q3 = q3*q3;          

// normalise the measurements
norm = sqrt(ax*ax + ay*ay + az*az);       
ax = ax / norm;
ay = ay / norm;
az = az / norm;
norm = sqrt(mx*mx + my*my + mz*mz);          
mx = mx / norm;
my = my / norm;
mz = mz / norm;         

// compute reference direction of flux
hx = 2*mx*(0.5 - q2q2 - q3q3) + 2*my*(q1q2 - q0q3) + 2*mz*(q1q3 + q0q2);
hy = 2*mx*(q1q2 + q0q3) + 2*my*(0.5 - q1q1 - q3q3) + 2*mz*(q2q3 - q0q1);
hz = 2*mx*(q1q3 - q0q2) + 2*my*(q2q3 + q0q1) + 2*mz*(0.5 - q1q1 - q2q2)
;         
bx = sqrt((hx*hx) + (hy*hy));
bz = hz;        

// estimated direction of gravity and flux (v and w)
vx = 2*(q1q3 - q0q2);
vy = 2*(q0q1 + q2q3);
vz = q0q0 - q1q1 - q2q2 + q3q3;
wx = 2*bx*(0.5 - q2q2 - q3q3) + 2*bz*(q1q3 - q0q2);
wy = 2*bx*(q1q2 - q0q3) + 2*bz*(q0q1 + q2q3);
wz = 2*bx*(q0q2 + q1q3) + 2*bz*(0.5 - q1q1 - q2q2);  

// error is sum of cross product between reference direction of fields and direction measured by sensors
ex = (ay*vz - az*vy) + (my*wz - mz*wy);
ey = (az*vx - ax*vz) + (mz*wx - mx*wz);
ez = (ax*vy - ay*vx) + (mx*wy - my*wx);

// integral error scaled integral gain
exInt = exInt + ex*Ki;
eyInt = eyInt + ey*Ki;
ezInt = ezInt + ez*Ki;

// adjusted gyroscope measurements
gx = gx + Kp*ex + exInt;
gy = gy + Kp*ey + eyInt;
gz = gz + Kp*ez + ezInt;

// integrate quaternion rate and normalise
q0 = q0 + (-q1*gx - q2*gy - q3*gz)*halfT;
q1 = q1 + (q0*gx + q2*gz - q3*gy)*halfT;
q2 = q2 + (q0*gy - q1*gz + q3*gx)*halfT;
q3 = q3 + (q0*gz + q1*gy - q2*gx)*halfT;  

// normalise quaternion
norm = sqrt(q0*q0 + q1*q1 + q2*q2 + q3*q3);
q0 = q0 / norm;
q1 = q1 / norm;
q2 = q2 / norm;
q3 = q3 / norm;

*tempQuat++ = q0;
*tempQuat++ = q1;
*tempQuat++ = q2;
*tempQuat++ = q3;
}
```

To get quaternion value `q0` ,`q1` , `q3`. Then I use this function:

```
void MPU6050_getYawPitchRoll(double * ypr,double *qu)
{
double gx, gy, gz;
double *tempQ = qu;

double q0,q1,q2,q3;
float sqw = q0*q0;
  float sqx = q1*q1;
  float sqy = q2*q2;
  float sqz = q3*q3;

q0= *tempQ++;
q1= *tempQ++;
q2= *tempQ++;
q3= *tempQ++;

gx = 2 * (q1 * q3 - q0 * q2);
gy = 2 * (q0 * q1 + q2 * q3);   
gz = q0 * q0 - q1 * q1 - q2 * q2 + q3 * q3; 
yaw = atan2(2* (q1 * q2 - q0 * q3), 2 * (q0 * q0 + q1 * q1) - 1) * 180 /   3.1416;  // YAW
pitch = atan(gx / sqrt(gy * gy + gz * gz)) * 180 / 3.1416;  // PITCH    
roll = atan(gy / sqrt(gx * gx + gz * gz)) * 180 / 3.1416;   // ROLL  

psi = atan2(2 * q1 * q2 - 2 * q0 * q3, 2 * q0*q0 + 2 * q1* q1 - 1)* 180 / 3.1416; // psi
theta = -asin(2 * q1 * q3 + 2 * q0 * q2)* 180 / 3.1416; // theta
phi = atan2(2 * q2 * q3 - 2 * q0 * q1, 2 * q0 * q0 + 2 * q3 * q3 - 1)* 180 / 3.1416; // phi
}
```

To get yaw, pitch, roll, psi, theta and phi.

In PC, I use openGL to draw 3D object. How can I use yaw, pitch, roll, psi, theta and phi to control that 3D object (rotation, translation)? Is that right?

```
glRotatef(-Yaw, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
glRotatef(-Pitch, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glRotatef(-Roll, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
```

Comment: Yaw, pitch and roll have to do with how the object is oriented (rotated), so you simply rotate the object by multiplying its model matrix by a rotation matrix. I also suggest using a helper library called 'glm' to do these calculations.

Comment: I try to use  glRotatef(-Yaw, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);glRotatef(-Pitch, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f);
glRotatef(-Roll, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f) after getting yaw, pitch, roll. Is that right to rotate the object? How about psi, theta and phi?

Comment: I believe you got it right, except pitch is rotation on the x-axis while roll is on the z-axis. So swap those. I haven't looked thoroughly into all of your calculation, but psi, theta and phi are normally equivalent to yaw, pitch and roll respectively. So you shouldn't need to use them at all.

Answer (score -1):

you doing it all the old way, why don't you use GLM ?
I did it this way in my project with cinder
I read _quat from MPU and arduino ...

```
vec4 axis = toAxisAngle(_quat);
// ...
rotate(axis[0], -axis[1], axis[3], axis[2]); // Note the orders and signs
```

and toAxisAngle :

```
/**
 * Converts the quaternion into a float array consisting of: rotation angle
 * in radians, rotation axis x,y,z
 *
 * @return 4-element float array
 */
static const float EPS = 1.1920928955078125E-7f;
vec4  toAxisAngle(const quat& q) {
    vec4 res;
    float sa = (float) sqrt(1.0f - q.w * q.w);
    if (sa < EPS) {
        sa = 1.0f;
    } else {
        sa = 1.0f / sa;
    }
    res[0] = (float) acos(q.w) * 2.0f;
    res[1] = q.x * sa;
    res[2] = q.y * sa;
    res[3] = q.z * sa;
    return res;
}
```